# How to blink a horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

Currently the horizontal scroll bar is visible only when the user is interacting with it.But I want the scroll bar should blink always so that the user can know that there is some item present to the right.I dont want to keep it visible always.If any one is having solution for it then please let me know.

### Horizontal scrollbar

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/featured_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/featured_bar"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: Blink ? You can use an Selector for that and use setSelected

Comment: @Kitesurfer : could you please give me some example of it or else redirect me to some site having this example.

Comment: And selector is an XML File which maps to some color/drawable for an state: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {


             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 

    @Override 
    public void run() { 
    horScrollViewOG.scrollBy(1, 0); 
    horScrollViewOG.scrollBy(-1, 0); 
    } 
    });
            }
        }, 0, 1000);

Check this, it will scroll the list view programtically, which will display the scroll bar
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I dont want to scroll rather I want to blink the scroll bar only.

Comment: Try the code dude, It will give you the blinking effect. Give it a try and then reply. Basically android makes the scrollbar visible when the list view is scrolling, but since we don't want to scroll, i have just scrolled it by 1px and reverted the scroll on next line, this scrolling wont be visible, Since it will scroll by 1px the scroll bars will be shown. Which solves the purpose...

Comment: Using a TimerTask is still overkill, as you can post on the UI Thread with an simple runnable. Anyway. the OT should define the Question more clear

Comment: Yeah I tried this code, but still the scroll bar is not visible but the logcat is showing that is is  scrolling.

Comment: Show me the horizontal scroll view attributes in xml.

Comment: try adding this property 
android:scrollbars="horizontal"
android:fadeScrollbars="true"
android:scrollbarFadeDuration="100"

Comment: lstView.scrollBy(1, 0);
            lstView.scrollBy(-1, 0);
Change this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29300/discussion-between-user2012-and-hardik4560)